# JellyBean behaves differently with picture capturing

Tags: android, android-api-levels

I am developing an Android app for Jellybean, KitKat and Lollipop and several different devices.

At the beginning of project, I used the Jellybean API library with target API 'anroid-18' using 'Samsung galaxy note 2014 edition'.
A few months later, the OS of the device started upgrading to KitKat OS,  so I changed the library to 'android-19' in which version number is 4.4.2.

I have new device named Galaxy S tab 2 now.

I have the three versions and two devices now and my default API is 4.4.2.

The problem occurred when capturing pictures using the app:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= AlopexBuild.VERSION_SUPPORT.KITKAT) {
       Intent mediaScanIntent 
          = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
       Uri contentUri = Uri.parse("file://"+ path); 
       mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
       sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
} else {
       sendBroadcast(
         new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ path)));
}
```

The following code has no problem in Jellybean:

```
Intent mediaScanIntent 
          = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
Uri contentUri = Uri.parse("file://"+ path); 
mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

Why is this happening?

Jellybean OS + Kitkat API = Failed

Kitkat OS + Kitkat API = OK

Lollipop OS + KitKat API = OK

Problematic code is 
  `sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ path)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the wiki articles references for each OS when releasing the new KitKat and Lolipop OS and moving from Jellybean they changed to a new kind of runtime enviroment. The code only compatible in this new enviroment, you'll need to try a different method for other enviroments like Jellybean. 
See [here](http://www.engadget.com/2013/11/06/new-android-runtime-could-improve-battery-life/) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_KitKat)